# How to find the source code of Wildfly in Eclipse debug

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I am using Wildfly 10 and Eclipse develop an application, and need to debug into a class TransactionScopedEntityManager through this "persist" method:

```
entityManager.persist(member);
```

However, in Eclipse when I pressed F5 to step into, I received

```
Source not found
Edit source lookup path
```

Where is the source of the class TransactionScopedEntityManager located? In my ~/.m2/repository/org/jboss/:

```
aesh/                 integration-platform/ jboss-parent/         jdf/                  marshalling/          remotingjmx/          shrinkwrap/           staxmapper/           weld/                                                        
arquillian/           jboss-dmr/            jboss-vfs/            logging/              remoting/             sasl/                 spec/                 threads/              xnio/
```

It has all those directories. Where to find the source code of the class?

Comment: Right Click on the Project>Maven>Download Sources?

Answer (score 3):

Download the "Application Server Source Code" zip from http://wildfly.org/downloads/ , expand it somewhere and configure the Source Lookup of Eclipse to also look into that folder.

Answer (score 2):

Download the source code, matching your runtime, from the wildfly project page. Extract to a location. Open the 'server view'. Select your server runtime and hit f3 (or rightclick and click 'open'). Click 'open launch configuration'. Go to tab 'Source'. Click 'Add'. Select 'File System Directory' and hit 'Ok'. Choose the location that you extracted the source to and check 'Search subfolders'. Confirm with 'OK'-

Answer (score 0):

The package path is
org.jboss.as.jpa.container.

The real file path is wildfly-master\jpa\subsystem\src\main\java\org\jboss\as\jpa\container.

If you need to find source code in Eclipse, you could use 'File Search' function in Eclipse. Press 'Ctrl+h' to open search panel, then select the tab 'File Search'. Now you could input keywords in Containing Text, and find them.

Comment: I searched "TransactionScopedEntityManager" but didn't find the file. I dont have the wildfly-master directory.

Comment: The wildfly-master directory is official source code of wildfly. Go to the github and search wildfly. You could download it from github. Here is the link https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly

Comment: I can download from there, but my application doesn't use it in my project. How can I use this source code in Eclipse debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I unzip WildFly 10 source code, did a search in File explorer for 
"TransactionScopedEntityManager.java", i found it is under
wildfly-10.1.0.Final-src\jpa\subsystem\src\main\java\org\jboss\as\jpa\container.

Manually edit the source path lookup, to point to directly "wildfly-10.1.0.Final-src\jpa\subsystem\src\main\java\", it may help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the source code for JBoss 7.2 EAP from here (JBoss login required):

https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download

Scroll down the list to 7.2.0 (other versions are also available).
Download the source zip file, extract to a local folder then follow the instructions from [mojoo-de's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049335/how-to-find-the-source-code-of-wildfly-in-eclipse-debug#answer-56123134).